# How do I map over an HList where all of the elements are instances of a typeclass?

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Let's say I have a typeclass such as this one:

```
trait Select[A] {
  def select(selector: String): Set[A]
}
```

The typeclass provides the functionality "given a selector string, gimme a set of `A` objects". However, it quickly gets tiring when you need to do this multiple times:

```
val setOfGrapes = Select[Grape].select("red-seedless")
val setOfApples = Select[Apple].select("fuji-apple")
// and so on...
```

My program lets users input strings that contain *multiple* selectors, so this all happens at runtime.

In the interest of making this more terse, how could I use shapeless to write a function that can be used like this?

```
val setOfGrapes :: setOfApples :: HNil =
  selectMultiple("red-seedless, fuji")(Select[Grape] :: Select[Apple] :: HNil)
```

The motivation is being able to quickly chain multiple `Select`s together. In essence, I am going from `Select[Grape] :: Select[Apple] :: HNil` to `Set[Grape] :: Set[Apple] :: HNil` by running a method from the `Select`.

Ignoring the string processing (handling commas, globs, and other things), how would I go about implementing this?

I've tried this:

```
object fun extends Poly1 {
  implicit def selectCase[A] = at[Select[A]](_.select(""))
}

def mapFun[H <: HList](inputs: H) = inputs map fun
```

The compiler tells me, `could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[fun.type,H]`. I assume this is because it cannot guarantee that every element of the HList is a `Select[A]`. How do I tell the compiler this?

I've tried specifying a [`shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint[H, Select]`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/ecc2f4e334fc5451c2bd4db65b4fb6cfcb6052e1/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/constraints.scala#L28) like this:

```
def mapFun[H <: HList](inputs: H)(implicit ev: shapeless.UnaryTCConstraint[H, Select]) = inputs map fun
```

But I receive the same error.

A friend recommended I use `Comapped`, `Mapper`, and `~>`, so I tried this:

```
object mapper extends (Select ~> Set) {
  override def apply[A](s: Select[A]): Set[A] = s.select(???)
}

def mapFun[II <: HList, OO <: HList](inputs: II)(
  implicit ev: Comapped.Aux[II, Select, OO],
  ev2: Mapper.Aux[mapper.type, II, OO]
): OO = input map fun
```

But the compiler `could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[ammonite.$sess.cmd8.fun.type,II]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should basically just add the required implicit evidence to your `mapFun` method:

```scala
object fun extends Poly1 {
  implicit def selectCase[A] = at[Select[A]](_.select(""))
}

def mapFun[H <: HList](inputs: H)(implicit m: Mapper[fun.type, H]) = inputs map fun
```

```scala
scala> mapFun(Select[Apple] :: Select[Grape] :: Select[Apple] :: HNil)
val res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Apple] :: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Grape] :: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Apple] :: shapeless.HNil = Set(Apple@44ebbbe8) :: Set(Grape@76eae32c) :: Set(Apple@666f67b6) :: HNil
```

To get your preferred API you can introduce a "manually curried" function like this:

```scala
class SelectMultipleApply(selector: String) {
  def apply[H <: HList](inputs: H)(implicit m: Mapper[fun.type, H]) = inputs map fun

  object fun extends Poly1 {
    implicit def selectCase[A] = at[Select[A]](_.select(selector))
  }
}

def selectMultiple(selector: String) = new SelectMultipleApply(selector)
```

```scala
scala> selectMultiple("red-seedless, fuji")(Select[Grape] :: Select[Apple] :: HNil)
val res5: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Grape] :: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Apple] :: shapeless.HNil = Set(Grape@63c81efa) :: Set(Apple@29dbae38) :: HNil
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thank you. I wish there were more literature on this.